# A solution of the ODE $xy''=y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions, frobenius-method

Consider the ODE
$$
xy''=y 
$$
in the interval $(0,\infty)$. By plugging
$$
y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n 
$$
in the ODE, it is not hard to see that $a_0=0$ and $a_{n}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)n}$ for all $2\leq n$. Hence, we obtain the solutions
$$
y=a_1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n!)^2}x^n
$$
where $a_1$ is arbitrary.

Since the ODE is of second order, it must have another independent solution. How can I find this solution? Thanks.

Comment: If $a_0=0$, then each of the coefficients $a_n=0$ from the recurrence you found (at least for $n>1$, since the denominator is $0$ for $n=1$). Why should $a_0=0$ be true? I don't think you carried out Frobenius' method correctly.

Comment: You right. The recurrence should  be true for $2\leq n$

Comment: $a_0=0$ since the left hand side is a power series of the form $b_0x+b_1x^2+\ldots$ while the right hand side is $a_0+a_1x+\ldots$

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are assuming an ordinary power series solution, but$$xy''-y=0 \implies y''-\frac1xy=0$$cannot be solved in the usual manner because $-\frac1x$ is non-analytic at $x=0$, hence you must use Frobenius' method. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) for more details. You have to start off with a more general series solution,$$y=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^{n+k}.$$

Comment: thanks @user170231